# How do I use reflection to configure all implementations of interface for DI as IOptions<>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, reflection, dependency-injection, configuration

## Introduction

I'm using IOptions<> in ASP to provide configuration to services. Currently I have to setup each POCO individually. I would like to do this in a generic way.

I would like to use some sort of reflection to automaticly configure all POCO's that are used for configuration injection with IOptions. Thus avoiding calling the `services.Configure<Poco>()` for each class.

## The working setup

My `appsettings.json` file.

```
{
  "DemoOption": {
    "OptionOne": "hello",
    "OptionTwo": "world"
  }
}
```

POCO for configuration section:

```cs
public class DemoOption
{
    public string OptionOne { get; set; }
    public string OptionTwo { get; set; }
}
```

Enables me to do this:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<DemoOption>(configuration.GetSection(nameof(DemoOption)));
}
```

And use it like this:

```cs
public class MyService
{
    public IOptions<DemoOptions> _options { get; set; }

    public MyService(IOptions<DemoOptions> options)
    {
        _options = options;
    }
}
```

### What I've got this far

To use reflection I create and add an `IOption` interface to my POCO class:

```cs
public class DemoOption : IOption // Added empty IOption interface
{
    public string OptionOne { get; set; }
    public string OptionTwo { get; set; }
}
```

This is where I'm stuck. I've gotten all the implementations of the `IOptions` interface, but I can't figure out how to call the `services.Configure()` method.

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // This actually works and finds all implementations.
    var options = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
        .Where(x => typeof(IOption).IsAssignableFrom(x) && !x.IsInterface && !x.IsAbstract)
        .Select(x => x).ToList();

    // This does not work
    foreach (var o in options)
    {
        // What should I write here?
        services.Configure<o>(configuration.GetSection(nameof(o)));
    }
}
```

All help appriciated.

Comment: Your question boils down to just how to call `Configure<TOptions>` via reflection, which is covered in the linked answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Configure** is a generic method so the type can only be evaluated at compile time.

There is no member available accepting instance of Type as a parameter in [IServiceCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.iservicecollection?view=aspnetcore-2.2) reference.

Another option would be to use a reflection to generate many more generic methods at runtime, it can work in the case but the approach itself is not quiet fast.